# JPA programmatically mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose there exists a compiled class `Person` that source code was like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String name;
...
}
```

I want map this class to JPA with transient `name` field.
In general, every combination are possible. For example `@Basic` to `@Lob` , `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` to `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` and so on.

**Question** : Does JPA allow me to do this?

**NOTE 1** : It may be possible by subclassing or using bytecode libraries (e.g. CGLib,javassist,..), but I want do this programaticlly and configurable when `EntityManagerFactory` will be created.

**NOTE 2** : I use hibernate 4.3 as JPA provider.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to subclass?  Seems like you can do it this way since annotations are not inherited

Comment: I don't want subclassing,for some reasons. The most important one is that subclassing isn't configurable.